# date arrives differently in salesforce

Tags: php, date, drupal, salesforce, salesforce-communities

[image]I am using drupal and I have webform where there is field date of production and there is calendar in this field When I put date 2020-09-30 in this field and submit my form it save this field wrongly in salesforce like this:
**6/9/2022** it changed to year 2022 and also changed month and day

following is the condition I have put in salesforce function

```
        function ublox_salesforce_salesforce_webforms_save_submission_alter(&$fields, $context) {
  foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, ["Date_Prototype__c", "Date_Production__c", "NBIOT_Date_of_Field_Trial__c", "NBIOT_Date_Lab_Trial__c"])) {
      $fields[$key] = trim($value);
      if ($fields[$key] == 'Date_Production__c') {
        $fields[$key] = format_date(strtotime($fields['Date_Production__c']), 'medium', 'm-d-Y');
      }
  }
```

You can see my if condition for 'Date_production__c' ( date of production start )
Where I am doing wrong? I am unable to find solution anyone can help me please.

I have also attached the screenshot of my field where I have put date 2020-09-30 but it reached differently like **6/9/2022** [image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What's the outcome of this `format_date(strtotime($fields['Date_Production__c']), 'medium', 'm-d-Y');`, can you write it to log or `echo` or something?

Salesforce API expects dates in `2020-09-14` format (so that'd be `Y-m-d`?) and datetimes in `2020-09-14T18:07:30Z` format. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: Hey, Yes I have attached the output but it displaying same as i enter in input field

Comment: If it displays `09/30/2020` then you have in there something trying to be smart and display it with current user's locale. My PHP is rusty and I never touched Drupal but if function has `-` in formatter and something makes `\` out of it - you have a problem. Seriously, just do what it takes to format it to `2020-09-30`. Maybe "medium" is poorly chosen parameter, custom formatter is used when you pass well, "custom"? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7.x